# VisuALG 3.0 - Invalid floating point operation

Tags: floating-point, calculator, divide-by-zero

I'm using **VisuALG 3.0** and I've already analyzed and fought where the floating point error ocurred, so I've been trying harder and searching about how to solve it, how to make it disappear when my calculator **divides 0 by 0** *(**And this is the invalid floating point operation**)*. My teacher asked me that and I accepted. I tried to use `ABS` too, but sincerely, I'm not right if I'm using it well, any answers or tips?

```
    v̲a̲r̲
    // Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
    OPCAO: inteiro
    NUM,N: real
    cont: caractere

    i̲n̲i̲c̲i̲o̲
    // Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
    Escreval("":21,"---------------------")
    Escreval("":22,"Calculadora Simples")
    Escreval("":21,"---------------------")
    Escreval("")

    //Loop
    Repita
    Escreval("OPÇÕES: ")
    Escreval("-------")
    Escreval("1- SOMA")
    Escreval("2- SUBTRAÇÃO")
    Escreval("3- MULTIPLICAÇÃO")
    Escreval("4- DIVISÃO")
    Escreval("5- POTÊNCIA")
    Escreval("6- RAIZ QUADRADA")
    Escreval("")
    Escreva ("Escolha uma opção clicando o número correspondente: ")
    Leia (OPCAO)

    //Funções se
    Se ((OPCAO < 1)ou(OPCAO > 6)) entao
    Escreval ("Este número não é uma das opcões!!!")
    Fimse

    Se ((OPCAO > 0)e(OPCAO < 6)) entao
    Escreva ("Introduza um número qualquer: ")
    Leia (N)
    Escreva ("Introduza mais um número: ")
    Leia (NUM)
    Escreval("")
    Se (NUM = 0) entao
    Escreval (N," /",NUM," = Impossível")
    fimse
    Se (OPCAO = 1) entao
    Escreval (N," +",NUM," =",N+NUM)
    Senao
    Se (OPCAO = 2) entao
    Escreval (N," -",NUM," =",N-NUM)
    Senao
    Se (OPCAO = 3) entao
    Escreval (N," x",NUM," =",N*NUM)
    Senao
    Se (OPCAO = 4) entao
    Escreval (N," /",NUM," =",N/NUM)
    Senao
    Escreval (N," ^",NUM," = ",N ^ NUM)
    fimse
    fimse
    fimse
    fimse
    fimse
    Se (OPCAO = 6) entao
    Escreva("Introduza um número qualquer: ")
    Leia(N)
    Escreval("")
    Escreval("Raíz de",N," é:",raizq(N))
    fimse

    Escreval("----------------------")
    Escreva ("Deseja continuar? S/N: ")
    Leia (cont)
    Se ((cont <> "S")e(cont <> "SIM")) entao
    interrompa
    fimse

    Escreval("")

    fimrepita
    f̲i̲m̲a̲l̲g̲o̲r̲i̲t̲m̲o̲
```

[This image can help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVkA7.png)

Comment: Someone wants me to change the code for English?

Comment: It is impossible?

Comment: I'm not understanding how this works...

Comment: Help? I need to know this, not for my teacher but for myself.